# Replace a href with a js function call

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, href, appcelerator

I want to replace an url in a href with a call of a function that needs to include the url.

example:
I have the following string:

```
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
some other text
<a href="www.wikipedia.org">Wikipedia</a>
```

I want to get back a string like this:

```
<a href="javascript:anyFunction('www.google.com');">Google</a>
some other text
<a href="javascript:anyFunction('www.wikipedia.org')">Wikipedia</a>
```

I have tested some ways with RegEx, but I'm not good with RegEx. Does anyone have a solution for my problem?

EDIT:
Sorry, I forgot to write. I'm building an appcelator application. I can't use jQuery or "document". I think the only way is a RegEx.

Comment: ahhh. So what you really want is not help with the html/css as we've been doing. You are seeking string replacement! Correct?

Comment: Exactly. Sorry for my bad description.

Comment: What language are you using the regex in? javascript? php? Sorry for the barrage of questions, but this will help get an answer for you :).

Comment: I'm using JavaScript. I've postet my current code as comment on your solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this regex a try:

```
/href="([^"]+)/g
```

Here is a sample of its usage ([JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dJ9tB/))

```
var subject = '<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>some other text<a href="www.wikipedia.org">Wikipedia</a>';
var result = subject.replace(/href="([^"]+)/g, 'href="javascript:anyFunction(\'$1\')');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you give your `hrefs` unique IDs you can do this:

```
var val = $("#myHref").attr("href");
$("#myHref").attr("href", "javascript:anyFunction('"+val+"');");
```

If you want to avoid unique IDs then you can do this (applied to all a's):

```
​$("a").each(function() {
    var val = $(this).attr("href");
    $(this).attr("href", "javascript:anyFunction('"+val+"');");
});​​​
```

If you want to avoid applying this to all hrefs you can give all the hrefs you want changed a class then use a selector like this: `$(".hrefToModify")...`

Comment: I can't use jQuery or something like this, because this is inside a appcelator application. Creating a new element does not work, too, because I can't use "document".

Comment: Ah, sorry. I'm afraid I can't help you then, it's been a while since I played around with Appcelerator.

Answer (score 0):

NEW:

If you can use javascript, then can you get access to the anchor tag itself? if so:

```
anchor_element.href = "javascript:anyFunction('" + anchor_element.href + "')";
```

OLD:

```
<a id="link1" href="www.google.com">Google</a>
some other text
<a id="link2" href="www.wikipedia.org">Wikipedia</a>

<script>
document.getElementById('link1').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    alert('hello');
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: like said in my upper comment, I cant use document :/

Comment: Interesting. Can you add any javascript code at all? Or do you only have access over html. What do you have access to in general?

Comment: Javascript is usable. I have added a regex to get the complete a-tag as string. But I'm not good with RegEx, I don't know how to replace the href. This: `pattern = /<a href="(.*?)">/;matches = htmlString.match(pattern);alert(matches[0]);` returns `<a href="www.google.com">`

Comment: are there other ways to get elements in javascript other than `document.getElementById`? My javascript skillz are weak :)